# Python loops: Making them more general

Tags: python, loops, collections

I am working on converting data in a date format to a new ID based on other information in the spreadsheet.  I want to also add _2,_3, etc. based on subsequent events in the same day.  So if there are 3 cases of 20101212 in the dateID, the last 2 events would have a _2 and _3 modified onto the ID.

How can I make my solution more general.  It works but it is not very reusable.  It is currently just hard coded as I know in this specific spreadsheet, there is no more than 3 cases of any specific date.  How can I write the code in order to catch events with more than 3 cases in the same day without continuing to add additional elif statements?

```
dateID = [some list of strings in date format]
GS = [some list of 2 letter strings to append to corresponding dates]
#len(GS) = len(dateID)
caseID = []
y = collections.Counter(dateID)
#len(y) < len(dateID)  
j = 0
for i in range(len(y)):
    num_iter = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][1]
    if num_iter == 1:
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j]
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
    elif num_iter == 2:
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j]
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j] + '_2'
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
    elif num_iter == 3:
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j]
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j] + '_2'
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j] + '_3'
        caseID.append(case)
        j = j + 1
    else:
        caseID.append('This catchs errors, add more elif num_iter == __') 


dateID = ['19820323','19831209','19840218','19840321','19840504','19841227','19841227','19850104','19850110','19850114']
GS = [u'Er', u'Er', u'Er', u'Er', u'Er', u'Mn', u'Mn', u'Er', u'Er', u'Er']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to loop as many times as `num_iter`. Something like

```
base_string = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0]
for iter in range(num_iter):
    case = base_string + GS[j]
    case += '_{0}'.format(iter + 1) if iter > 0 else ''
    caseID.append(case)
    j += 1
```

Note that this will only work if you want to *continue* in the same format. I've also refactored `sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0]` into `base_string` for better performance and readable code.

Comment: Thank you as well.  I understand now that your solution is to have me add another loop on top of this one.  The pythonic way of writing code confused me at first as I still have too many steps in my coding.

Answer (score 1):

without being able to test against some data, try this:

```
dateID = [some list of strings in date format]
GS = [some list of 2 letter strings to append to corresponding dates]
#len(GS) = len(dateID)
caseID = []
y = collections.Counter(dateID)
#len(y) < len(dateID)  
j = 0
for i in range(len(y)):
    num_iter = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][1]
    for k in range(num_iter):
        append_string = '_' + str(k + 1) if k != 0 else ""
        case = sorted(y.iteritems())[i][0] + GS[j] + append_string
        caseID.append(case)
        j += 1
```

Comment: You're overwriting the global variable `j` which will mess up the asker's code's indexing system for the list `GS`.

Comment: It's still not correct, `j` is used to access the next element in `GS`. Your code repeatedly retrieves only the first `num_iter` values in `GS`.

Comment: thank you, I should take a bit more care next time... I believe it should be correct now.

Comment: Yes it is. Don't worry, all of us face problems when coding without an IDE and/or without being able to debug, especially when it isn't our code :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  I have been working through your answer trying to understand it fully.  It works beautifully, and has taught me a great deal!